# Python - Multiple line printed image not displaying correctly issues

Tags: python, printing

I am having some issues with displaying images for Rock - Paper - Scissors. I'm very new to python (3 weeks) and I am trying to print a multiple line 'image'.
Please excuse my terrible art!

```
import random

def Display_Rock():
    print ("""\n
   _---___
  / .#.... \
 / .$../\.. \
 |_________/
""")

def Display_Paper():
    print ("""\n
 __________
|~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~|  
|~~~~~~~~~~| 
|__________|
""")

def Display_Scissors():
    print ("""\n

    _----_
   / /--\ \     
  |  \__/  \_________________
   \____                     \
    /       ------------------\
   /  /--\  _________________/
   |  \__/  /
    \-____-/          
 """)
 Display_Rock()
 Display_Scissors()
 Display_Paper()
```

This displays the following -

```
   _---___
 / .#.... / .$../\.. |_________/




         ----_
       / /--\ \     
      |  \__/  \_________________
       \____                       /       ------------------ / /--\   
      _________________/            
      |  \__/  /
       \-____-/          



       __________
      |~~~~~~~~~~|
      |~~~~~~~~~~|
      |~~~~~~~~~~|
      |~~~~~~~~~~|
      |~~~~~~~~~~|  
      |~~~~~~~~~~| 
      |__________|
```

Thank you for reading and for any comments in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `r` before of your strings like so:

```
def Display_Rock():
    print (r"""
   _---___
  / .#.... \
 / .$../\.. \
 |_________/
""")

>>> Display_Rock()

   _---___
  / .#.... \
 / .$../\.. \
 |_________/
```

Python treats your `\` as escape chars.

Answer (score 1):

While the others are correct, you can also escape the `\` so that it is not treated specially by adding another `\`:

```
print ("""\n

    _----_
   / /--\ \\     
  |  \__/  \_________________
   \____                     \\
    /       ------------------\\
   /  /--\  _________________/
   |  \__/  /
    \-____-/          
""")
```

In future Python versions the `\` cannot be used unescaped, so starting from 3.6 a warning will be emitted for `\_`, `\-` and `\`, so from there on you must always use `\\` to mean `\`; alternatively you can use the `r''` raw strings; though then you cannot use `\n` for newline.